# How to change Keys of entities from Long to String in Google AppEngine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, primary-key

I have many entities of one type which have Key with auto-generated Long ID (e.g. Person(1234)), but now I need to change those keys to have String name instead (e.g. Person("username")).

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add a username attribute to the entity and get (using query) the entity by user name.
2. When creating the Person entity provide a key_name (Person(key_name=username, ...) ), but you will need to migrate all the existing Person entities by recreating them.

Comment: I've already made this choice and decided for 2). My question is directed to the way of migration of the existing entities. So what you say is that the only way is to create a new entity with a new key, copy all properties from the old entity and then delete the old one?

Comment: @JakubStejskal yes that is pretty much what you have todo

Answer (score 0):

Once an entity has been saved to the datastore, it's key cannot be changed. So you'll either have to make do with the existing keys, or create new entities with the new keys and remap any existing pointers to the original entities.